# why unsatisfied constraints appeare after adding a AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I want to add a video background to my viewController's main view, and the adding code is like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //moviePlayer is an instance of AVPlayerViewController()
    moviePlayer.view.frame = view.bounds
    //view is the main view of my view controller
    view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(moviePlayer.view)

    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("moments", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    moviePlayer.player = player
    moviePlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
    moviePlayer.player?.play()
    moviePlayer.player?.volume = 1
}
```

it works very well. But there are warning messages saying that `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`. Here is part of the printed debug messages.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1c8ee9870 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7fd1c8e33c50.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7fd1c8d74190.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1cb067250 H:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x7fd1c8eac130'Slide your finger down to...']   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fd1c8e33c50 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1cb0672d0 H:[UILabel:0x7fd1c8eac130'Slide your finger down to...']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fd1c8e33c50 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1cb066a60 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7fd1c8d74190]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fd1c8d73250 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1cb066af0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7fd1c8d74190]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fd1c8d73250 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1cb066790 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fd1c8d73250]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fd1c8d71f60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1cb066810 H:[UIView:0x7fd1c8d73250]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fd1c8d71f60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1c8db9790 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fd1c8d71f60(0)]>"
```

)

Actually, my main view has nothing but the `moviePlayer's` main view. And when i check what the printed constraints are, i find many strange views, such as `_UIBackdropView`, `AVAlphaUpdatingView`. What's that? and I can't find these views in the `debug view hierarchy`. But they cause the unnecessary constraints. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What might be happening is that your movie player view is automatically setting up constraints. Have you tried setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO on `moviePlayer.view`?

Comment: @CraigMcMahon yeah, i have tried that. But it does not work.

Comment: Why are you sending it to the back? If its the first object there, it will be @ the back? remove addSubviewtoBack

Comment: @user3069232 i removed it. but the warning messages did not disappear.